# isc-dhcp host using files

Tags: hosts, isc-dhcp, hosts-file

I configured ise-dhcp-server, which works fine, but my dhcpd.conf is starting to become very big. I'm trying to find information (without results), on whether it's possible to use something like `import /path/to/file`. I want to use it to set static host in this separate file.

Everywhere people write only to use it to path to pxe/grub image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `include "/path/to/file";` directive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work .I was tried it before I wrote this post. After add `include "static-hosts/10.1.1";` in the subnet, the ise-dhcp-service won' t reload/restart/start.

Comment: What error message do you get? (BTW you should have mentioned that you tried the include directive).

Comment: I just find the error, When I was create file with hosts, I don't delete all in `dhcpd.conf`, so I had a duplicates.